# How do I make div with overlapping contents scale with window size and be centered?

Tags: html, css

I have multiple images I want to position within a div, overlapping one another (mostly within each png image's transparent background). I want to have the whole set of images within the div scale and re-position to look the same but at a smaller size as the size of the browser window changes. How can I do this and also have the div center horizontally within the browser window?

I have an example of the issue I'm having in a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vug5yrdb/16/

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        .gwd-img-1kkt {
          position: absolute;
          left: 1.76%;
          top: 1.04%;
          width: 25.2%;
          height: 47.24%;
        }

        .gwd-img-1c79 {
          position: absolute;
          left: 2.08%;
          top: 28.88%;
          width: 25.2%;
          height: 29.2%;
        }
        .gwd-img-12uj {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0.06%;
          top: -7.61%;
          width: 35.22%;
          height: 79.77%;
        }

        .wrapper {
          position:relative;
          padding: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KG8oR83.png" id="red-bit" class="gwd-img-1kkt">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GQqpTkb.png" id="teal-bit" class="gwd-img-1c79">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iBIXHX3.png" id="blue-bit" class="gwd-img-12uj">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This version scales appropriately, but is not centered and is stretched.

Comment: It's not a good way to do this stuff

Comment: Is there a good way? I'm trying to do a collage type effect.

Comment: You just declare image inside an image, I mean using position absolute and then make a tight position using left, top, bottom, right property. position absolute makes your code harder to manage. If you want to do only this photo then you can do this what you have done but if you want to make a gallery like this plz use grid or flexbox instead of doing this! ALways be simple not simpler/ harder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust your code like below. I added a border to illustrate the centring:

```css
.gwd-img-1kkt {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20.52%;
  top: 2.08%;
  width: 50.4%;
  height: 94.48%;
}

.gwd-img-1c79 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 21.16%;
  top: 57.76%;
  width: 50.4%;
  height: 58.4%;
}

.gwd-img-12uj {
  position: absolute;
  left: 17.12%;
  top: -15.22%;
  width: 70.44%;
  height: 159.54%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width:50%; /* this will control the horizontal size*/
  margin:50px auto;
  outline:1px solid;
}
.wrapper::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:70%; /* this will control the vertical size */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KG8oR83.png" id="red-bit" class="gwd-img-1kkt">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GQqpTkb.png" id="teal-bit" class="gwd-img-1c79">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iBIXHX3.png" id="blue-bit" class="gwd-img-12uj">
</div>
```